# Change RabbitMQ Management Plugin refresh rate

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ Management plugin auto refreshes the page in selected intervals of 5, 30 or 300 seconds.
I want it to refresh it every 1 second. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Its too late reply :P but for the sake of documentation I am answering this.

You can try a quick hack with the management plugin.

Steps:

Unzip the management plugin:

```
cd /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.7.4/plugins
unzip rabbitmq_management-3.7.4.ez
cd rabbitmq_management-3.7.4

vim rabbitmq_management-3.7.4/priv/www/js/tmpl/layout.ejs

 [...]
    <option value="5000">Refresh every 5 seconds</option>    
    <option value="10000">Refresh every 10 seconds</option>
    <option value="30000">Refresh every 30 seconds</option>
    <option value="">Do not refresh</option>
[...]
```

Edit with appropriate values (in your case 1000 --> Refresh every 1 second)

Move old plug in:

```
cd /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.7.4/plugins/
mv rabbitmq_management-3.7.4.ez /myhome/rabbitmq_management-3.7.4.ez
```

Zip the the plugin directory

```
zip -r rabbitmq_management-3.7.4.ez rabbitmq_management-3.7.4
```

Restart the rabbitmq service.

-Rahul N.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that 5 secs can be changed. I noticed that the message count returned by the api - http://username:password@rabbitmq_server:15672/api/queues/%2f/your_queue_name also updates only after every 5 seconds even if if you keep sending requests to it.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to change the Management UI refresh rate, @Rahul Nair answer works fine.

But I wanted to increase the refresh rate of the detailed stats obtained via the api (`/api/overview` => `message_stats.ack` in order to ensure my message was acked before running checks in integration tests).

I added this section to file `/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config`:

```
[
    {rabbitmq_management_agent, [
        {sample_retention_policies, [
            {global,[{605,5},{3660,60},{29400,600},{86400,1800}]},
            {basic,[{605,5},{3600,60}]},
            {detailed,[{605,RMQ_DETAILED_STATS_REFRESH_INTERVAL}]}
        ]}
    ]}
].
```

Where you can set `RMQ_DETAILED_STATS_REFRESH_INTERVAL` to 1 (this is the minimal value, unfortunately) instead of 5 by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why someone ever need 1sec resolution, maybe you should use [Management HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_1_3/priv/www/api/index.html) rather then web interface?

But yes, technically it is possible. You may change some option value to 1000 and select it or use some browser extension like [userscript](http://userscripts.org/) to do that for you every page visit. The other way is to get into management plugin and make it return an extra option in select.